# JointJS: Unable to display a foreignObject in a custom shape with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, svg, jointjs, foreignobject

I am trying to define a custom shape in JointJS that includes a  tag.  If I define the markup as a string, it works just fine:

```
joint.shapes.examples.CustomRectangle = joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle.define('examples.CustomRectangle', {
  markup: '<rect class="card"/><foreignObject x="10" y="10" height="60" width="100"><input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="text"></input></foreignObject>',

  attrs: {
    rect: {
      refWidth: '100%',
      refHeight: '100%',
      strokeWidth: 5,
      stroke: '#000000',
      fill: 'white'
    },
  }
});
```

See this codepen and note that the input box is visible inside the square: http://jsfiddle.net/dovrosenberg/kbmwfg1a/89/

If I define what appears to be the same XML inside the SVG but using JSON:

```
joint.shapes.examples.CustomRectangle = joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle.define('examples.CustomRectangle', {
  markup: [{
      tagName: 'rect',
      selector: 'rect'
    },
    {
      tagName: 'foreignObject',
      selector: 'fo',
      attributes: {
        x: '10',
        y: '10',
        width: '60',
        height: '100',
      },
      children: [{
        tagName: 'input',
        selector: 'inpt',
        attributes: {
          xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
          type: 'text',
        },
      }]
    }
  ],
  attrs: {
    rect: {
      refWidth: '100%',
      refHeight: '100%',
      strokeWidth: 5,
      stroke: '#000000',
      fill: 'white'
    },
  }
});
```

See this codepen and note that the input box is not visible:
http://jsfiddle.net/dovrosenberg/asnvwe1r/4/

When I look at it in the browser, the resulting SVG looks virtually the same.  The only differences I can see are the JSON version inserts `joint-selector` attributes, but I wouldn't think that would matter.

Stranger yet, if you edit the HTML in the debugger and make a minor change to the foreignObject tag (say changing one of the joint-selector attributes) then the input becomes visible.

Shouldn't this work?

Comment: xmlns is not a real attribute - you can't set it with setAttribute and have it work properly. It's the element's namespace and it's there because the element was created in the right namespace by createElementNS rather than createElement. Editing something forces the parser to reparse the elements, fixing the namespace problem.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson!  That makes sense and led me to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the great comment from Robert Longson, I was able to figure it out.  The right markup is as below (or see http://jsfiddle.net/dovrosenberg/asnvwe1r/8/).  The difference is the new `namespaceURI` key.

```
joint.shapes.examples.CustomRectangle = joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle.define('examples.CustomRectangle', {
  markup: [{
      tagName: 'rect',
      selector: 'rect'
    },
    {
      tagName: 'foreignObject',
      selector: 'fo',
      attributes: {
        x: '10',
        y: '10',
        width: '60',
        height: '100',
      },
      children: [{
        tagName: 'input',
        selector: 'inpt',
        namespaceURI: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attributes: {
          type: 'text',
        },
      }]
    }
  ],
  attrs: {
    rect: {
      refWidth: '100%',
      refHeight: '100%',
      strokeWidth: 5,
      stroke: '#000000',
      fill: 'white'
    },
  }
});
```